# Node API recive result from async node module to separate module

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous

I am having a heck of a time trying to get the results of an API call to pass through to an AIP request from another node module.  I have a module that searches for a series name and returns that series name and its id.  I have another node module that accepts a search query from my front end form.  I want the webAPI.js module to take the search request pass it to the thetvdb.js module and send the results back to the webapi.js function that originally called it.

So far all I can get is to return a result of undefined or promise pending.  But no matter what I do the console.log for the return result in the webAPI.js always returns without the information and then the console.log in my thetvdb.js will return with the results I am looking for.

## thetvdb.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('node-fetch');
const requestURL = require('request');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let scanLocation = 'downloads/'

// The TVDB
const TheTVDB_URL = 'https://api.thetvdb.com';
const TVDB_KEY = process.env.TVDB_API_KEY;
const TVDB_API_VERSION = 'v2.1.1';
const TVDB_AV_HEADER = `application/vnd.thetvdb.${TVDB_API_VERSION}`;
const TVDB = require('node-tvdb');
const tvdb = new TVDB(TVDB_KEY);

exports.getSeriesNameAPI = function (seriesName) {
  let results = [];
  tvdb.getSeriesByName(seriesName)
    .then(response => {
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        let series = {
          name: response[i].seriesName,
          id: response[i].id
        }
        results.push(series);
        // console.log('name:', response[i].seriesName, 'ID:', response[i].id);
      };
      console.log('TVDB Raw:', JSON.stringify(results));
      return JSON.stringify(results);
    })
    .catch(error => { throw (error) });
};
```

## webAPI.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const async = require('async');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const superagent = require('superagent')
const Router = express.Router;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser').json();

const TVDBapi = require('./thetvdb.js');
// const app = express();

const webAPI = new Router();

webAPI.route('/search/:search').get((req, res) => {
  // console.log('WebAPI Results: ', TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search));

  Promise.resolve(TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search)).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  
  // async function getSearchResults(req){
  //   let response = await TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search)
  //   let data = await response
  //   while(data === undefined){
  //     if(data === undefined){
  //       console.log('async is worthless')
  //       // await res.send(JSON.stringify({'async':'worthless'}))
  //     } else {
  //       console.log('I cant belive it actually worked!')
  //       await console.log('inside Async:', data);
  //       await res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  //     }
  //   // searchResults = data;
    
  // }
  // getSearchResults(req);
  // console.log('WebAPI Results: ', getSearchResults(req));

  // res.send(JSON.stringify(getSearchResults(req)));
  // res.send(JSON.stringify(searchResults));


  // console.log('WebAPI Results:', fetch(TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search)));

  // let results = TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search).then(console.log('WebAPI results:', results));

  // async function init(req) {
  //   let results = await TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search)
    
  //   console.log('WebAPI results:', results);
  // }
  // init(req);
  
  // async.series(TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search), function (err, result) {
  //   /* this code will run after all calls finished the job or
  //      when any of the calls passes an error */
  //   if (err) { return console.log(err) };
  //   console.log('async result:', result);
  // });

  // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //   const error = false;

  //   if(!error){
  //     console.log(TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search));
  //     resolve()
  //   } else {
  //     reject('response borked')
  //   }
  // })

});

module.exports = webAPI;
```

In the end what I would like this to do is return the search results to the front end web interface. But all I get is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

**thetvdb.js**

```js
exports.getSeriesNameAPI = function (seriesName) {
  let results = [];
  // return Promise
  return tvdb.getSeriesByName(seriesName)
        .then(response => {
            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                let series = {
                    name: response[i].seriesName,
                    id: response[i].id
                }
                results.push(series);
            // console.log('name:', response[i].seriesName, 'ID:', response[i].id);
            };
            console.log('TVDB Raw:', JSON.stringify(results));
            return results;
        })
        .catch(error => { throw (error) });
};
```

**webAPI.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const async = require('async');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const superagent = require('superagent')
const Router = express.Router;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser').json();

const TVDBapi = require('./thetvdb.js');
// const app = express();

const webAPI = new Router();

webAPI.route('/search/:search').get( async (req, res) => {
  // console.log('WebAPI Results: ', TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search));
  try{
      //await promise resolve
      const response = await TVDBapi.getSeriesNameAPI(req.params.search);
      res.json(response)
  } catch (err) {
      res.json({result:'falure'})
  }
})
```